# Algorithm to reduce a large data set into a smaller set?

Tags: charts, reduce, waveform

I have a large data set (10's of billions) of data points (doubles) that I need to display on a chart. Since displaying all of the data at once is not useful, I was looking for an algorithm that will help me pick the best N points from the whole set.

I am currently doing [Systematic Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29#Systematic_sampling) to reduce the dataset. Any suggestions on how to improve on it? Thanks.

Update: The data is 16 bit signed numbers signifying the amplitude of a waveform. So they can range in value from -32,768 to 32,767. I want to capture the peaks and valley so that the N points picked to display from the whole set give an approximation of the entire set.

Comment: Data is data, charts are charts... without context they don't mean much. What information about the data are you trying to display? You need to define what makes one data point 'better' than another to find the 'best N' points

Comment: Agreed with glowcoder, you'd need to define how you determine a data point to be "better" than another one. How much does the data vary from one point to the next?

Comment: The data is 16 bit signed numbers signifying the amplitude of a waveform. So they can range in value from -32,768 to 32,767. I want to capture the peaks and valley so that the N points picked to display from the whole set give an approximation of the entire set.

Comment: I don't see what the problem with Systematic Sampling is? It'll be what comes to mind first. It is an "unbiased" solution, and very efficient. Do even you experience any real problems? Of course, if it only makes sense to show a "wave" that typically lasts 50 timepoints, you'd sample 50 sequential timepoints  every now and then rather than just a single point every now and then.